# Combine Events - Event Handler Passing

Tags: jquery

I can't for the life of me figure out how you would do the following:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var cb = $(this).parent().next().find("input[type=checkbox]");
  $(this).val().length > 0 ? cb.attr('checked', true) : cb.attr('checked', false) 
});
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
  var cb = $(this).parent().next().find("input[type=checkbox]");
  $(this).val().length > 0 ? cb.attr('checked', true) : cb.attr('checked', false) 
});
```

As one function.  Really don't like repetition, especially when they're doing the exact same thing.

My jQuery jedi skills aren't tailored to this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first declare the function:

```
function myFunc() {
   var cb = ...
}
```

and then add the assignments:

```
$('select').change(myFunc);
$('input[type=text]').keyup(myFunc);
```

Comment: All too easy.  I failed because I was doing `$('select').change(myFunc())` I believe.  Thanking you squire!

Comment: ah, yes. that would execute `myFunc` immediately and try to pass the *return value* of myFunc to the change listener.